# Kendo Grid multiple selection maximum row count

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

We are using `Kendo Grid(Asp.Net Mvc)` for users task table.Users will select up to 10 tasks and start the operation with a button located at the bottom of the grid.We have to restrict the max selection of rows. We have set the `GridSelectionMode.Multiple` selectable mode.

```
    @(Html.Kendo().Grid<TaskModel>()
    .Name("TaskModelGrid")
    .Selectable(s => s.Mode(GridSelectionMode.Multiple))
    .Columns(columns =>
    {
        columns.Bound(c => c.TaskName);
        ...
    })
    .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "height: 550px;" })
    .Scrollable()
    .Groupable()
    .Sortable()
    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
        .Ajax()
        .Read(read => read.Action("GetUsersTask", "TaskController"))
        .PageSize(20)
    )
)
```

Are there any settings or ways we can use? We checked the documentation but could not find anything.Any ideas will be appreciated. Thanks for help.

Comment: Murat, did you have a luck with my answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kendo doesn't have an out of the box support for max selected rows. Use the `Change` event to catch an array of selected rows and de-select extra rows. The basic working code is as follow where the user can select 10 rows at max.

### .cshtml

```
.Events(e=> e.Change("onRowChange"))
```

---

```
function onRowChange(e)
{
    /* get all the selected rows */
    var items = e.sender.select();
    items.each(function(i, e) {
      /* allows user to select 10 rows max */
      if (i > 9) {
        $(e).removeClass("k-state-selected");
      }
    });
}
```

Check out the demo [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/imsangram/s2fw70d8/2/).

Answer (score 2):

I bet you could do this with a count check on the grid change event:

```
....

.Events(e=> e.Change("onGridRowChange"))

...
function onGridRowChange()
{
    var grid = $('#grdMyGrid').data('kendoGrid');
    var selectedRows = grid.select();
    console.log(selectedRows.length);
}
```